# PySpark: How to judge column type of dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose we have a dataframe called `df`. I know there is way of using `df.dtypes`. However I prefer something similar to

`type(123) == int # note here the int is not a string`

I wonder is there is something like:

`type(df.select(<column_name>).collect()[0][1]) == IntegerType`

Basically I want to know the way to directly get the object of the class like `IntegerType, StringType` from the dataframe and then judge it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**TL;DR** Use external data types (plain Python types) to test values, internal data types (`DataType` subclasses) to test schema.

---

First and foremost - You should never use

```py
type(123) == int
```

Correct way to check types in Python, which handles inheritance, is

```py
isinstance(123, int)
```

Having this done, lets talk about

> Basically I want to know the way to directly get the object of the class like IntegerType, StringType from the dataframe and then judge it.

This is not how it works. `DataTypes` describe schema (internal representation) not values. External types, is a plain Python object, so if internal type is `IntegerType`, then external types is `int` and so on, according to the rules defined in the [Spark SQL Programming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types).

The only place where `IntegerType` (or other `DataTypes`) instance exist is your schema:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "foo")])

isinstance(df.schema["_1"].dataType, LongType)
# True
isinstance(df.schema["_2"].dataType, StringType)
# True

_1, _2 = df.first()

isinstance(_1, int)
# True
isinstance(_2, str)
# True
```

Answer (score 2):

What about trying:

```
df.printSchema()
```

This will return something like:

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- col4: date (nullable = true)
 |-- col5: long (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

If there's a need to check **detail structure** under `ArrayType` or `StructType` schema, I'd still prefer using `df.dtypes`, and then use `XXXType.simpleString()` from the *type object* to verify the complex schema more easily.

For example,

```py
import pyspark.sql.types as T

df_dtypes = dict(df.dtypes)
# {'column1': 'array<string>',
#  'column2': 'array<struct<fieldA:string,fieldB:bigint>>'}


### if want to verify the complex type schema
column1_require_type = T.ArrayType(T.StringType())
column2_require_type = T.ArrayType(T.StructType([
    T.StructField("fieldA", T.StringType()),
    T.StructField("fieldB", T.LongType()),
]))

column1_type_string = column1_require_type.simpleString() # array<string>
column2_type_string = column2_require_type.simpleString() # array<struct<fieldA:string,fieldB:bigint>>

# easy verification for complex structure
assert df_dtypes['column1'] == column1_type_string  # True
assert df_dtypes['column2'] == column2_type_string  # True
```

I think it's helpful if need to verify complex schema. This works for me (I'm using PySpark 3.2)